# SharePoint 2013 and ARR not working

Tags: 2013, reverse-proxy

I installed and configured SP 2013 with 1 site and 1 MySite. Everything's fine.

Now I installed an ARR according to different guides.

From a client pc, if I modify my host file to IP_ARR `SharePoint.Site`, I reach the login dialog box, and from the ARR I can see it serves request, and not failed. But when I log in, it leads me nowhere except : IE can't show this web page.

On SP 2013, my web app is hostnamed (with AAM) `SharePoint.Site` and the other one : `MySharePoint.Site`.

I disabled ssl offloading, I checked certificates.

I don't really know how to troubleshoot since error seems coming from SharePoint...

Comment: both sites are in single web app or different webapp? did you track it via fiddler? also in host file did you put the ip of web app?

Comment: check this article http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/05/using-application-request-routing-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-sharepoint/ and let us know if it fix the issue

Comment: This is one of the guides I followed. So I'll not publish two web app, only MySharePoint.Site (which a MySite sites collection). So now, I get redirected to login box, I enter credentials, and then it returns "401 unauthorized" (I tried SP adminsitrator, user, farm admin, the same ...). And yes, in the hosts file, I put IP of ARR and name of SharePoint MySite

Comment: MySharepoint.site is root level site in that web app?

Comment: Yes, I just found that wherever I'm connecting from, I get this error ... So this is SharePoint's fault. I'll investigate so

Comment: On my SP Server, "SharePoint Web Services Root" app pool was stopped ... I've just started it

Comment: Ok, so : I double check, my AAM wasn't good, so I added `https`, I unchecked the require SSL in SharePoint's IIS. Now it seems working ...

Comment: Now I'd like to be able to access directly MySite, even for the first time ... Because now, I got an error because user didn't do "First Experience" ... Is there a way to pre-configure this ? (I tried powershell with `$web.Properties[“urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:SPS-O15FirstRunExperience”]=”OFF” ` but it does not seem to work, maybe I should try IISReset ? ...